# Google Maps Fragment View not rendering content

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android studio project where I am using a map view fragment. In my old project, it worked well and displayed a map, but in my new one, the map is just blank (grey). Even the google logo is missing on the map.

Here is my logcat error log:

```
2018-11-16 13:14:20.286 1627-5883/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=mls.client/.clientviews.MapActivity (has extras)} from uid 10020 on display 0

    --------- beginning of main
2018-11-16 13:14:20.290 1372-1392/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4547748 , only wrote 4547520
2018-11-16 13:14:20.303 6528-6528/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2018-11-16 13:14:20.303 6528-6528/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2018-11-16 13:14:20.310 1627-1639/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 6528:mls.client/u0a83 for activity mls.client/.clientviews.MapActivity
2018-11-16 13:14:20.330 1307-1323/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1536000
2018-11-16 13:14:20.363 2148-2359/com.android.launcher3 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fae0980: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa0d57ee0)
2018-11-16 13:14:20.500 6528-6528/mls.client W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/mls.client-1/lib/x86
2018-11-16 13:14:20.532 6528-6528/mls.client I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2018-11-16 13:14:20.540 6528-6544/mls.client I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
2018-11-16 13:14:20.545 6528-6544/mls.client E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
2018-11-16 13:14:20.546 6528-6544/mls.client E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
2018-11-16 13:14:20.609 6528-6528/mls.client I/zzy: Making Creator dynamically
2018-11-16 13:14:20.614 6528-6528/mls.client W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
2018-11-16 13:14:20.621 6528-6528/mls.client W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
2018-11-16 13:14:20.621 6528-6528/mls.client W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
2018-11-16 13:14:20.664 6528-6528/mls.client I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8298000
2018-11-16 13:14:20.667 6528-6528/mls.client I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 12874026
2018-11-16 13:14:20.706 6528-6528/mls.client E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
2018-11-16 13:14:20.832 6528-6557/mls.client D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2018-11-16 13:14:20.899 1627-1741/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10083 on display 0
2018-11-16 13:14:20.910 1307-1355/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-11-16 13:14:20.982 6528-6584/mls.client I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-11-16 13:14:20.982 6528-6584/mls.client D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2018-11-16 13:14:20.982 6528-6584/mls.client W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2018-11-16 13:14:20.982 6528-6584/mls.client D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2018-11-16 13:14:20.986 6528-6584/mls.client D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa3586320: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2018-11-16 13:14:20.989 6528-6584/mls.client D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3586320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3583ae0)
2018-11-16 13:14:20.990 6528-6584/mls.client E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2018-11-16 13:14:20.991 6528-6584/mls.client E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2018-11-16 13:14:21.015 6528-6528/mls.client W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2018-11-16 13:14:21.024 6528-6584/mls.client D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3586320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3583ae0)
2018-11-16 13:14:21.099 1627-1813/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2100 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:389 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.notifyAppStopped:4463 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityStoppedLocked:1252 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityStopped:6903 
2018-11-16 13:14:21.109 1627-5883/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(3, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$GpsRequest@88ac655)
2018-11-16 13:14:21.109 1627-1640/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(3, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$GpsRequest@88ac655)
2018-11-16 13:14:21.111 1715-1906/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3585780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3583730)
2018-11-16 13:14:21.297 1627-1648/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting mls.client) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2100 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
2018-11-16 13:14:22.871 6528-6581/mls.client W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
2018-11-16 13:14:22.871 6528-6581/mls.client W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via V2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mls.client-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/mls.client-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2018-11-16 13:14:22.875 6528-6581/mls.client I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
2018-11-16 13:14:22.875 6528-6581/mls.client I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
2018-11-16 13:14:23.516 1372-1393/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4855373 , only wrote 4702320
```

Any idea what is going wrong with my MapView?

if you need more info or code, please write me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the Google Maps Android API is enabled in your Developer's Console. If it is, check if you put the Android API Key in the google_maps_api.xml

Answer (score 0):

go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

update Application restrictions with used domains and API restrictions with used API.

the changes takes more than 5 mins to reflect